# PHP MYSQL ROW SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, database, row

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['FirstName'];
  echo $row['LastName'];
  }
```

I want it with a $i ++ so i get 1 then 2 and so on, so i can make like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
if($i == 1){
<div>
  echo $row['FirstName'];
  echo $row['LastName'];
</div>
}
elseif($i == 2){
  echo $row['FirstName'];
  echo $row['LastName'];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want?

Comment: You should not use the ancient mysql_* api anymore!! It is being deprecated by the community!

Comment: You should also NOT use the `*` in the SELECT clause, it leads to maintenance and performance problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just create the counter variable yourself, like so:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $i++;
  if($i == 1){
  ...
  ...
  else if ($i == 2) {
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: It works but it need to reset when it hits nr 2.... And you do it with this code it $i == 2 $i = 0;

Answer (score 1):

You can't have PHP and HTML code randomly thrown in together.
From PHP to write out html content.

**Incorrect**:

```
if($i == 1){
<div>
...
```

**Correct**:

```
if($i == 1){
echo "<div>";
...
```

Comment: But better yet store the markup into a variable `$markup` and echo it in the end, only once.